# Linear Fit Issue

Tags: calculus, mathematical-modeling

Consider a quantity $Q$ that changes as a function of time.
The function $Q(t)$ is not explicitly known. We know
that $Q(t_{0})=Q_{0}$. Assume for $t-t_{0}\le\epsilon$,
we have a method to estimate one additional point on the $Q(t)$ curve. This estimation gets better
for small $\epsilon$. Given the inital point and
another point, for a fixed epsilon, it seems that
one can approximate $Q(t)$
by  a linear function. However the nature of the linear
function seems to change based on $\epsilon$ that one picks.
What is the best way to estimate $Q(t)$ in this case? 
Thanks -abiyo

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are missing: because you have chosen a linear model, $T = at + c$, so $\frac{t_1 - t_0}{T_1 - T_0} = \frac{1}{a}$. By the nature of the linear model that you have chosen, $T(t) \in O(t)$, so the limit of their ratio must be real-valued.

Comment: Thanks Orangutango for the reply, I want to have an explicit expression for $t_{r}$. In my case, $T_{1}$ is more precise when $t_{0}-t_{1}<\epsilon$. Now where I am stuck is writing an explicit expression for $t_{r}$ that doesn't depend on epsilon

Comment: You realize that by shrinking $\epsilon$ to zero, you are losing the linear information, don't you? You can't describe a line with only one point, which seems to be what you are trying to do. Honestly I find your model very unrealistic, both in that temperature does not decay linearly and that you would never take measurements at a sample rate where this became a problem.

Comment: Orangutango, thanks once again. I agree the example I gave is rather poor. For my actual case, I am trying to give some estimate for the decay of pressure at a fixed point in space behind a shock wave. One of the quasi-analytical forms known in the literature for this case is the exponential decay. It is just that in the way I derive my solution, I have an initial point. The additional point will be known precisely if I am arbitrarily closer to the initial point. I have edited the question to reflect your comments.